# Programmatically unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am displaying a UIView with a UITableView control on it.  I display this view with a Show segue, by calling performSegueWithIdentifier.  In the module from which the segue is called, I have added a function that I want to use on unwind, to retrieve some data from the view upon return from the segue.  Right now, I have a Done button that is hooked up to the function on the caller, so that I can retrieve the data from the segue when it unwinds.  Instead of doing this all when the Done button is tapped, I would like to do it when an item is selected in the UITableView.

In tableView(,willSelectRowAtIndexPath), I try calling popViewControllerAnimated.  The second UIView does close and bring me back to the calling UIView, but the unwind function is not called.

I know how to set up the unwind from the done button, using Exit, but I cannot figure out how to do it when tapping on a row in the UITableView.

Here's the code that I'm using to execute the segue:

```
    @IBAction func fromButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentButton = sender.tag

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UnitsSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Here's the code that executes when the segue is unwound:

```
@IBAction func returnFromUnitSelection(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    var buttonToSet: UIButton!
    var unitsToSet: UnitData!

    fromLabel.text = "0"
    toLabel.text = "0"

    if let unitsSelectionViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? UnitSelectionController {
        if currentButton == 0 {
            fromUnitData = unitsSelectionViewController.selectedUnit
            buttonToSet = fromButton
        }
        else {
            toUnitData = unitsSelectionViewController.selectedUnit
            buttonToSet = toButton
        }

        setButtonText(buttonToSet, firstLine: unitsSelectionViewController.selectedUnit.unitCode, secondLine: unitsSelectionViewController.selectedUnit.unitName, firstLineFontSize: 15, secondLineFontSize: 11)
    }
}
```

Here's the code that I use to close the second UIView:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    selectedUnit = temperatures[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    return indexPath
}
```

The unwind code does execute when I tap Done.  But nothing happens when I select an item in my table.

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create unwind segue for entire view controller. To do this drag segue from view controller objet to exit object. [image]

After segue created it is listed in document outline.

[image]

Select it and give it an identifier in attributes inspector. Then inside your code when when tableview selects a cell perform this segue like any other normal segue.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let title = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text

    performSegueWithIdentifier("backToViewController1", sender: title)
}
```

Then override `prepareForSegue` method to pass data to first view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier where identifier == "backToViewController1",
       let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController,
           selectedTitle = sender as? String {
        destination.selectedCountryTitle = selectedTitle
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  I didn't have to override prepareForSegue.  When I dragged from the view to exit, a popup displayed with my unwind function.  I'm not really sure why or how it knew to display that particular function.  I selected it and put the performSegueWithIdentifier in my tableView function, and it worked.

Comment: Overriding prepareForSegue is necessary if you need to pass data to first view controller

Comment: Why i can't  drag segue from view controller objet to exit object ?

Comment: You have to right click and drag from view controller to exit